# Why does COM Interop treat a VB6 Boolean as C# Short?

Tags: c#, .net, com, vb6, com-interop

I have a legacy VB6 application that has the following structure defined:

```
Public Type DrawDown
    Date As Date
    Amount As Currency
    CapitaliseInterest As Boolean
End Type
```

An interop assembly is generated using `tlbimp.exe` but the structure ends up as the following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public struct DrawDown
{
    public DateTime Date;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Currency)]
    public decimal Amount;
    public short CapitaliseInterest;
}
```

I'm using .NET 4.0.

Why does the VB6 `Boolean` get translated to a C# `short` instead of a `bool`?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't reorder the members?

Comment: I'm sure. The C# is copied from the assembly opened in **JustDecompile**.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with VB6 to be certain but it certainly seems wrong that the fields are being re-ordered.  Either case though Davide's answer about the actual types involved is correct.

Comment: @JaredPar It's been some times since I've had to dig into what VB6 was doing behind the scenes but I vaguely recall that if you changed source order of fields it would try to maintain memory order to avoid breaking binary compatibility. Don't take my word on that one though, as I said it's been a while.

Comment: @JonHanna: Out of curiosity I used **OleView** to check the layout in the type library. It matched the ordering of the VB6 source code. It's strange that the order is changed in the interop assembly.

Comment: @JonHanna & @JaredPar: Ok, **JustDecompile** must be broken (it is beta) because I've checked it using **ILSpy** and the order matches the VB6 code and additionally, the `struct` is marked with `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]`.

Comment: Well, I can't remember the pack rules for VB6, so I've no idea if that's right or not (if I knew it's all muddled with every other cases either something had to be word-aligned, and every other case that something had to *not* be word-aligned :) Did you try to code to see if it actually worked? I must admit my curiosity is piqued.

Comment: Presumably JustDecompile isn't broken then. Interesting.

Comment: No, I'd say it is broken. The code snippet in my updated question contains the output from **ILSpy** which has the members ordered in the same sequence as the VB6 code. **JustDecompile** had the members ordered wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

VB6 uses the VARIANT_BOOL type,

find info and history about it here: [BOOL vs. VARIANT_BOOL vs. BOOLEAN vs. boo](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/22/329884.aspx)

> Off to the side came VARIANT_BOOL.
>
> typedef short VARIANT_BOOL; define VARIANT_TRUE ((VARIANT_BOOL)-1)
>   define VARIANT_FALSE ((VARIANT_BOOL)0) This was developed by the
>   Visual Basic folks. Basic uses -1 to represent "true" and 0 to
>   represent "false", and VARIANT_BOOL was designed to preserve this
>   behavior.

Answer (score 8):

Because it is one.

VB6 bools are 16-bit values where 0 is false and any non-zero is true, but something set to true is set to -1 (0xFFFF). This way a lot of combinations of bools with numbers works well with VB6 because `x AND TRUE` gives `x`, `x OR FALSE` gives `x`, `x AND FALSE` gives `FALSE` and so on, with the same logic for bit-wise and boolean operators. Unfortunately it also means that `4 AND 2` is false despite that being `TrueThing AND OtherTrueThing`, so cautious VB6 coders didn't over-rely upon this, but used `CBool` to force the value to be either 0 or -1.

In general we have the choice of using natural machine size for the machine-processing speed versus using a single byte as it's the smallest addressable unit and hence gives a size advantage. Back when the natural-size on 16-bit machines was, well 16-bits of course, the balance went more in favour of going for the natural size than today when we've 32-bit and 64-bit machines. Visual Basic 1.0 ran on DOS and Windows 3.0 which could run on Intel 80286 16-bit processors, so it's not that strange a choice.

In the COM world, we have VARIANT_BOOL, which is just another way of saying "a bool, done the way VB6 does them", to allow for compatibility across langauges. The closest thing in C# would be either `short` or `ushort`, and if we cared only about C# we could pick either. Firstly though, we tend to use signed more than unsigned values, which would lean us toward `short`, but also `ushort` is not a CLS-compliant type, and there's hardly any point introducing an incompatibility with other .NET languages in obtaining compatibility with COM! Hence `short` is the clear choice.

Answer (score 2):

The `Boolean`, under the hood, is essentially a short integer:

```
False = 0, True != 0
```

Generating the interop assembly resolves this.

Documentation per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2t3725f.aspx) on this.

> 4-byte integer value where any nonzero value represents true and 0
>   represents false. This is the default format of a Boolean field in a
>   structure and of a Boolean parameter in platform invoke calls.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the /VariantBoolFieldToBool flag to tlbimp.exe to make it generate a C# bool member instead of the short.

See the [official documentation for tlbimp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx.aspx)